# How do I start the postgreSQL service upon boot?

Tags: 10.04, startup, services, postgresql

I am running PostgreSQL (v 8.4) on Ubuntu 10.0.4.

The PG service currently starts on reboot (after I installed PG on my machine), however, I want the service to use a new data directory.

Currently, after a reboot, I have to:

1. Stop the currently running PG service
2. manually type: `/usr/local/pgsql/bin/pg_ctl start -D /my/preffered/data/directory -l /usr/local/pgsql/data/logfile`

Which file do I need to edit to ensure that I always have the service using the correct data folder?

Answer (score 1):

You should edit the file `postgresql.conf`. Where to find this file and a lot of other information can be found in [postgresql's manual (18.1 and 18.2)](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/runtime-config.html).

On my system (natty) this file is in `/etc/postgresql/8.4/main`. The variable you have to change is `data_directory`.